# Removing tablet responsive design

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design, width, tablet

I have a WordPress website I'm coming to an end in finishing.

I want to remove the iPad format which is in the media queries (3 css files linked below) and I've toyed around with the pixels width here and there but everytime I remove or adjust them, I seem to just break the styling completely and not allow the website to continue the same layout from desktop.

3 CSS Files that are linked with all of this:

Layout.css - http://185.123.96.64/~curiouse/wp-content/themes/curiousegg/css/layout.css

Style.css - ( Inspect element, unable to post more than 3 links just yet)

Responsive.css - http://185.123.96.64/~curiouse/wp-content/themes/curiousegg/css/responsive.css

---

URL: (Self explanatory, only 2 links I can post unfortunately)

I'm happy with the responsive change for a mobile, however the iPad resolution (around 768px) I would happily do without.

I have spent a long time tweaking this through FTP so I've had to resort to some extra eyes to help look at this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Dev

Comment: If your theme has been designed in a "mobile first" way as kind of every theme does, you can't do that.

Comment: The transition occurs at 800px and under, so trimming it to 790px and few other changes wouldn't help? Is 800px the generic cap for this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in a mobile first development, your base is the mobile css, then you add your rules for tablets, then on top of that your rules for desktop. So if you remove the tablet rules, you'll loose the style that desktop use as base.

Sadly there is no quick proper way to remove that breakpoint, though I guess you could do something dirty like setting your tablet media query to `767px` and change your desktop media query to `768px` to be sure it take over. Not ideal but it should work.

Comment: I'll give this a shot and see how it goes

Comment: What files and line is it you suggest to change? I've tried this and that but it's not panning out right.